# Write array values in CSV

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, file-handling

I have an array of elements, which i need to store in separate cells  using Perl file handling.

```
foreach(@type)
{
print FH qq|"@type","@date","@loc","@title"\n|;
}
```

I use the above code, but its only stores last element in the array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: all variable have same number of values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `foreach (@type)`, the special variable `$_` is assigned the values of `@type` one after one. In your code, you are not using the variable `$_`. On the contrary, you output `@type`, the array you are iterating over. You probably wanted to iterate over the indexes, something like

```
for (0 .. $#type) {
    print FH qq("$type[$_]","$date[$_]","$loc[$_]","$title[$_]"\n);
}
```

or, with a named loop variable:

```
for my $index (0 .. $#type) {
    print FH qq("$type[$index]","$date[$index]","$loc[$index]","$title[$index]"\n);
}
```

Note that if your columns might contain newlines or double quotes, you would be better off with [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to write a CSV file, it's a good idea to use a specific module from CPAN that will helps you a lot. For example, [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm). There are a lot of small details you may forget in a custom implementation of the CSV format.